# Why does mariabackup always give me access denied?

Tags: mariadb

**Context**

Running MariaDb 10.6.7 on Windows 11. Trying to use mariabackup to do a partial backup of my database. Database, target backup folder and backup process all on the same PC.

**Issue**

In a batch file I have this:

```
cd C:\"Program Files\MariaDB 10.6\bin"
mariabackup --backup --target-dir='D:\OneDrive\Backups\MariaDb' --databases-exclude="*test" --user=root --password=myPasswordWithNoQuotes
```

Which keeps giving me the response:

```
Failed to connect to MariaDB server: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**Things I've checked**

- Running the batch file as administrator
- root has full priviliges
- Password is correct - checked by logging into root with MySQL Workbench and MySQLClient and HeidiSQL.

**Question**

How do I set access rights so that the backup can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the root password to something simple everything worked. So it looks like the issue was a special character in the password (a % character perhaps) or the way that the password parameter was formed in the mariabackup command.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows shell expansion. Did you try single quoting it?

Comment: @danblack yes, both single and double quotes., No joy. I’m pretty sure it was to do with a % sign in the password but I didn’t spend time figuring out how to escape that.